# Normalizing a file path in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js script that takes a filename argument, which it then consumes using require():

**json2csv.js**

```
var filename = process.argv[2]; 
var parsedJSON = require(filename);
```

I run this as follows:

```
$ node json2csv.js ./inputFile.json
```

This works so long as I either explicitly prefix the file (if local) with "./" or I use an absolute file path. However, if I omit the "./", e.g.:

```
$ node json2csv.js inputFile.json
```

I get a "Cannot find module" error, because node is interpreting the filename as a module name. Is there a standard way to munge file paths in node so that they are output either as an explicit local path or an absolute one?

I know it's not difficult to write for my scenario; I'm just looking for a standard way that would work across platforms. I found [Path.normalize()](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p), but that actually strips any leading "./".

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`path.resolve()`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to), optionally passing [`process.cwd()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) for *`from`*:

```
var path = require('path');
var filepath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), process.argv[2]);
```

Examples:

```
console.log(path.resolve('/foo/bar', 'baz'));   // "/foo/bar/baz"
console.log(path.resolve('/foo/bar', './baz')); // "/foo/bar/baz"
console.log(path.resolve('/foo/bar', '/baz'));  // "/baz"
```

Though, to avoid [caching](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) with `require()`, you should read the file directly:

```
fs.readFile(filepath, function (err, jsonData) {
    var result = JSON.parse(jsonData);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You really shouldn't use `require` like that. Rather you should do:

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename));
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I had to do: fs = require('fs') first, then it worked. Although I had to pick Jonathan's answer as the official one, since it more concisely answers my question.

Comment: Note that this is not true for known-good .json files (e.g. configuration files). And more importantly, note that the above code _needs_ to be in a `try/catch` block because `JSON.parse` can and will throw an error on malformed JSON, and you should have code in place to deal with that.